# Как сделать OS на весь экран в VirtualBox на Ubuntu 22.04 (Ubuntu-физическая машина)?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

1. При нажатии на кнопку "Insert Guest Additions CD Image" ничего не происходит.
2. Кнопка в меню "Auto-resize Guest Display" нактивна.
3. Другие кнопки из меню экран не увеличивают.
4. Дополнения устанавливала:

```
    $ sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

```
    $ sudo apt install gcc make perl
```

5. Настройки меняла:

```
    $ VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution any
```

```
    $ VBoxManage setextradata win10 CustomVideoMode1920x1080x32
```

5. [Репозиторий «Universe» включала](https://ixnfo.com/kak-vklyuchit-repozitoriy-universe-v-ubuntu.html)
6. Комп и VirtualBox перезагружала

```
    $ systemctl restart virtualbox.service
```

```
    $ sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load.service
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стоп-стоп-стоп. В хосте максимум что надо поставить - экстеншн-пак. А вот уже внутри гостя - Открыть этот образ: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.34/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.34.iso и поставить exe файл. И перезагрузить гостя.

Answer (score 0):

virtualbox-guest-x11 устанавливаются внутри windows.

Разрешение экрана в виндовс настраивается мышкой правой кнопкой по рабочему столу, если гест тулс не заработает. И потом фулскрин.